# Cancelled API requests

Tags: angular

I have a header which has a couple of get requests to an API. Sometimes (only sometimes) when I login and get redirected to a page (or refresh the page manually), one or two get requests get cancelled. Often it's the `getCompany` request, but it can vary. I don't get why...

`Header.component.ts`:

```
export class HeaderComponent {
    mbtn;
    loggedInAs;
    showp1;
    showp2;
    showMessageTemplate;
    showOverlay;
    displayOverlay: boolean;
    showSpinner: boolean;
    buttonText: string;
    homeData: any;
    isLoggedIn: any;
    companies: any;
    companyName: string;
    companyId: any;
    userName: string;
    userType: any;
    currentCompanyId: any;
    company: any;
    id: any;
    companiesName: string;
    homeUrl: any;
    userCharacterString: string;
    urlData: any;
    loaded: boolean;
    companiesloaded: Promise<boolean>;
    companyloaded: boolean;

  constructor(private location: Location,private loginService: LoginService, private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router, private homeService: HomeService, private userService: UserService, private companyService: CompanyService) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === 'true') {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
    else {
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }

    this.router.events.pipe(filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).forEach(next => {
       
          this.currentCompanyId = this.route.snapshot.firstChild.params['defaultCompanyId'];

          this.getHomeData();
        });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.getCompaniesData();
    }

    this.buttonText = 'Logga in som arbetsgivare';
    this.loggedInAs = localStorage.getItem("loggedInAs");
  }

  getHomeData() {
    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.getUser();
    }

    if (this.isLoggedIn && this.currentCompanyId) {
      this.getCompany(this.currentCompanyId)
    }
  }
  
  getCompaniesData() {
      this.userService.getCompaniesData().subscribe(companies => {
        this.companies = companies.Data;
      })
  }

  getCompany(currentCompanyId) {
    this.companyService.getCompanyData(currentCompanyId).subscribe(company => {
          this.company = company?.Data;
          this.companyName = this.company?.Name;
          this.companyId = this.company?.Id;
        })
  }

  getUser() {
    this.userService.getName().subscribe(user => {
      this.userName = user.Data;
    })
  }
}
```

`UserService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  public sharedDataForCompanies$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getCompanies() {
    if (!this.sharedDataForCompanies$) {
      this.sharedDataForCompanies$ = this.getcCompanies();
    }
    return this.sharedDataForCompanies$;
  }


  private getcCompanies() {
    return this.http.get("/Users/GetCompanies/").pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    )
  }

  getPersonName(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>("/Users/GetName/")
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('getUserName', []))
      );
  }

  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>("/User/GetUser")
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('getUser', []))
      );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

}
```

CompanyService:

```
  getCompany(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>("/Company/GetCompany/" + id)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<any>(' "Error while loading company"', []))
      );
  };

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
```

My app.component.html looks like this:

```
<div>
  <alert></alert>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div class="loading" *ngIf="loading">
    <img src="../Content/Images/Preloader_3.gif" />
  </div>
  <app-footer [version]="version"></app-footer>
</div>
```

Component inside router-outlet that I'm on (or get redirected to) when this happens looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.data.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.userDetails = res.user?.Data;
      this.subtext = this.userDetails?.Subtext;
      this.header = this.userDetails?.Header;
      this.companies = this.userDetails?.Companies;
        this.dataSource.data = this.companies;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    });

  }
```

and resolver for that component:

```
export const UserResolver: ResolveFn<any> = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  const userService = inject(UserService);
  const id = Number(route.paramMap.get('id')!);

  return userService.getUser().pipe(mergeMap(data => {
    if (data) {
      return of(data);
    } else {
      // user not found
      router.navigate(['/pageNotFound']);
      return EMPTY;
    }
  }));
};
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out!

Comment: It's natural that requests are canceled when you manually refresh the page

Comment: ok, why? I can see now that it not only happens when I manually refresh page but also when I get logged in and redirected to that page. Will update my question